# Date display in handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Here is what I have (the relevant part of it).

Handsontable options:

```
data: [[new Date(2013,5,26,17,00,00),24.7025,null,29.018950276,19.7746530531,null,null,null,null,null,null,55,110,165,220], ...

columns: [{type:'date', dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'},{type: 'numeric',format: '0,0.00'}, ...
```

Result as shown in the handsontable date cell:

```
Wed Jun 26 2013 17:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)
```

I would like to show it as "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", but I haven't found a way to do so... the display seems to always stick to the default date format, as shown above.

Comment: can't you use `to_date` function??

Comment: In my case (for other reasons regarding compatibility with other objects) the source must remain in the native javascript date, which in this example is `new Date(2013,5,26,17,00,00)`. My only margin here is to force Handsontable to format this native javascript date into a formatted string through its option `columns`.

Comment: Could you show your full handsontable initialization code and perhaps some more background?

Answer (score 2):

In such case you can use custom renderer.

I have created jquery.handsontable.exts.js and I'm loading it with handsontable.js.

This sample script uses renderFormat or dateFormat property to render the date correctly.

```
    /**
    * Handsontable date renderer
    * @param {Object} instance Handsontable instance
    * @param {Element} TD Table cell where to render
    * @param {Number} row
    * @param {Number} col
    * @param {String|Number} prop Row object property name
    * @param value Value to render (remember to escape unsafe HTML before inserting to DOM!)
    * @param {Object} cellProperties Cell properites (shared by cell renderer and editor)
    */
    Handsontable.DateRenderer = function (instance, TD, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
        if (value && typeof value == "object" && value.constructor == Date) {
            // Date!
            var format = cellProperties.renderFormat || cellProperties.dateFormat || "";
            value = $.datepicker.formatDate(format, value); //value.format(format);
        }
        if (cellProperties.readOnly)
            Handsontable.TextRenderer(instance, TD, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties);
        else
            Handsontable.AutocompleteRenderer(instance, TD, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties);
    };

    Handsontable.DateCell.renderer = Handsontable.DateRenderer;
    Handsontable.cellLookup.renderer.date = Handsontable.DateRenderer;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's 4 years later and I've found the answer in the [Handsontable documentation](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta5/demo-date.html). I thought I would share anyway...

```
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: getDataFromSomewhere(),
    colHeaders: ['SomeText', 'SomeDate'],
    columns: [
      {
        // 1st cell is simple text, no special options here
      },
      {
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        correctFormat: true,
        defaultDate: '01/01/1900'
      }
    ]
});
```

The downside of this is that you need to use three extra libraries:

- /dist/moment/moment.js
- /dist/pikaday/pikaday.js
- /dist/pikaday/css/pikaday.css

And it automatically adds a daypicker (which is not what I wanted anyway... I need to have `HH:mm` as well).

Answer (score 0):

```
    columns: [
        { data: 'Changed', renderer: dateTimeRenderer, readOnly: true },
    ],

function dateTimeRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    value = typeof value === "undefined" ? '' : new Date(value).toLocaleString();
    return Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties);
}
```